# for loop Arduino/C

Tags: for-loop, arduino, iteration, control-flow

My aim is to create a for loop that iterates through numbers and once it reaches the maximum, it stops printing. So far I managed to create a piece of code that stops printing the x but it keeps printing zeroes. How can I stop Serial.print() function to be executed once the iteration reached the maximum value?

```
int x;
boolean f = false;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  for(x=0;x<8;x++){
    Serial.println(x);
    delay(300);
    if(x==7){
      f = true;
    }
    if(f){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should serve. Btw, I like to name my vars something meaningful to avoid potential confusion and make the code more intelligible.

(In general you are better off posting questions to the [Arduino forum](http://arduino.cc/forum/). More traffic and more knowledgeable/helpful people == more likelihood of getting an answer.)

```
int current;
int limit;
boolean complete;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  current = 0;
  limit = 8;
  complete = false;
}

void loop(){

  if (!complete){
    while (true){
      Serial.println(current);
      current++;
      if (current >= limit){
        complete = true;
        break;
      }
      delay(300);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not want to open a topic on the Arduino forum just for this. Excellent answer btw, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The key is the word `loop` - that function is called repetitively!

If you want something to happen once, do it in `setup()`, or (as another answer suggests), have a flag to keep track of the fact that you've done it already.

Another way (since `x` is global) would be:

```
void loop() {
  if (x < 8) { 
     Serial.println(x);
     x++;
   }
}
```

or, getting rid of the global variable:

```
void loop() {
  static int x = 0;
  if (x < 8) { 
     Serial.println(x);
     x++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x;
boolean f = false;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

Very similar to your code, just put the print statement in the if statement and you're set.

```
void loop(){
  for(x=0;x<8;x++){
    if(!f) {
      Serial.println(x);
    }
    delay(300);
    if(x==7){
      f = true;
    }
  }
}
```